# Shortest Route Algo Terribly Slow

Tags: c#

first post.

I wrote a shortest-path script for a Unity game project, and while it works, it gets so slow when applied at scale that it crashes Unity when executed. This is to say, it works slowly for a single test character, but scale is required for the project.

I didn't really follow any of the known shortest path techniques to create it, rather I did it myself. The way it works is that it spawns a series of recursive methods each containing a for loop to explore each possible node in the network, bringing with each method a pathway and a list of pathways. If the target is found, or if the current path gets longer than a known path, or if a new node has already been inspected, the method terminates.

Here is some code. I have excluded the method that initially calls this recursive method:

```
void ExploreBranch(List<Point> stem, List<List<Point>> masterList, Point target)
{
    if (masterList.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < masterList.Count; m++)
        {
            List<Point> thisList = masterList[m];
            if (stem.Count + 1 >= thisList.Count) 
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    Point lastPoint = stem[stem.Count - 1];
    for (int c = 0; c < lastPoint.Connections.Count; c++)
    {
        List<Point> updatedRoute = new List<Point>(stem);
        Point newConnection = new Point();
        newConnection = lastPoint.Connections[c];
        if (newConnection == target)
        {
            updatedRoute.Add(newConnection);
            masterList.Add(updatedRoute);
            return;
        }
        if (updatedRoute.Contains(newConnection))
        {    
            continue;
        }
        updatedRoute.Add(newConnection);
        ExploreBranch(updatedRoute, inspected, masterList, target);
    }
}
```

So, basically this is nowhere near efficient enough and I can't figure out a way within this basic framework to improve it. I am now leaning in the direction of starting over or trying to get really experimental, but thought I would check here first.

One of the main things here is that I need to preserve the actual pathway, which the character needs to use and follow within the game. So it's not just that I need to know how short the path can be, I also need the actual path.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hey Colin, welcome to the site.  Just a query - you mentioned that you'd created this algorithm yourself, rather than trying to implement a known algorithm; implying that you're aware you could implement an existing solution... That makes sense if you're trying to learn... but likely people answering on here may just give you an implementation of such an algorithm... Is that what you're after, or are you looking more for tips on inefficiencies with your implementation / guidance on how to improve?  For that, maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site?

Comment: Hi @JohnLBevan , thanks for replying. I haven't used one of the known algorithms because I am not sure in what way this one is inferior. That is not to say it's not, it probably is, and I am certainly not averse to using one of them! (I need to get this done.) I looked at some of the known ones but my brain could only think in these terms in order to make it work.

I guess what I'm saying is: if someone here is going to tell me that this implementation is terribly inferior and to use breadth-first or Dijkstra, that is fine -- I just am not experienced enough myself to know that.

Comment: This algorithm is recursive and it looks like it does an exhaustive search. That probably explains why it is slow and crashes when scaled up. Changing the algorithm will improve stability and performance in this case far more than optimizing the algorithm.

Comment: In your code you're calling the recursive function `ExploreBranch` before you repeat your loop.  This means you're doing depth first instead of breadth first (i.e. you're going down one specific path, rather than looking at the next route for each path; which is generally more efficient as it'll find the shortest paths first, rather than investing effort in one arbitrarily route, then investing all effort in a next arbitrary route, etc).  There's a good video with diagrams and code here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaBhtODEL0w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend just using Dijkstra since you seem aware of that. It is rather simple to implement, and can be extended to A* that is theoretically optimal.

I honestly do not understand the code example, so I'm basing this from the description of your algorithm. I apologize if I have misunderstood something.

Consider an infinite grid, where cells are evaluated in the top, right, bottom, left order. Where the starting node is just left of the target node. A simple depth first algorithm like you describe would evaluate the top-node first, and then the top-node of that one, and so on. Since the grid is infinite it would never never reach the target, even when they are just next to each other. I'm also unsure if it would actually guarantee the shortest path with your termination conditions, since nodes can be reached by multiple paths, and the first one found does not have to be the cheapest.

A breadth-first algorithm like djikstra would order the evaluated nodes according to the distance from the starting node, so it would quickly reach the target, even with a infinite graph.

The A* refinement would order the evaluated nodes according the the distance from the starting node + estimated remaining distance , and that is significantly more efficient. But it introduces some complexity, like how the estimation is done. Especially if the weight of the edges has large variations. And there are further refinements that can improve performance by using approximate solutions, or uses some extra knowledge about the graph.